# How to build up a sparse output from given records in SQL Server statements?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Given some records

```
declare @t table
           (
                idx varchar(10),
                class varchar(10),
                head varchar(10),
                qty VARCHAR(10)
           )

insert @t (idx, class, head, qty)
values ('row1', 'H1', 'C1', 1), ('row1', 'H1', 'C2', 2),
       ('row1', 'H1', 'C3', 3), ('row2', 'H2', 'D1', 2),
       ('row2', 'H2', 'D2', 3), ('row2', 'H2', 'D3', 4),
       ('row3', 'H1', 'C2', 8), ('row3', 'H2', 'D2', 9),
       ('row3', 'H2', 'D3', 10), ('row4', '', '', ''),
       ('row5', 'H2', 'D2', 10), ('row5', 'H2', 'D3', 11),
       ('row5', 'H3', 'E1', 12), ('row6', '','','')

SELECT * FROM @t
```

OUTPUT:

```
idx memo    class   head    qty
--------------------------------
row1    ida H1  C1  1
row1    ida H1  C2  2
row1    ida H1  C3  3
row2    id  H2  D1  2
row2    id  H2  D2  3
row2    id  H2  D3  4
row3    id  H1  C2  8
row3    id  H2  D2  9
row3    id  H2  D3  10
row4    ida         
row5    idf H2  D2  10
row5    idf H2  D3  11
row5    idf H3  E1  12
row6    id
```

How to make a spare array output like below efficiently?  **ZERO**s could be replaced by blank string. A similar question and answer in `Mathematica` could be found here.https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/186835/building-a-sparse-array-from-given-lists-the-2nd-case

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"arrays" are not something SQL is generally known for although Postgres does have array features.

In T-SQL you can "pivot" you table, like this:

```
SELECT idx, [C1],[C2],[C3],[D1],[D2],[D3],[E1] 
FROM (
        SELECT
              idx, head, qty
         FROM @t 
   ) sourcedata
pivot
    (
         max([qty])
        FOR [head] IN ([C1],[C2],[C3],[D1],[D2],[D3],[E1])
    ) p 
order by idx
```

which will produce this:

```
+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|    | idx  |  C1  |  C2  |  C3  |  D1  |  D2  |  D3  |  E1  |
+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|  1 | row1 | 1    | 2    | 3    | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
|  2 | row2 | NULL | NULL | NULL | 2    | 3    | 4    | NULL |
|  3 | row3 | NULL | 8    | NULL | NULL | 9    | 10   | NULL |
|  4 | row4 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
|  5 | row5 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 10   | 11   | 12   |
|  6 | row6 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
+----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

and you can even generate the pivot query if needed:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(head)
            FROM some_table s
            where head is not null and head <> ''
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
        ,1,1,'')

SET @query = 'SELECT idx, ' + @cols + '
 FROM (
        SELECT
              idx, head, qty
         FROM some_table 
     ) sourcedata
 pivot
    (
         max([qty])
        FOR [idx] IN (' + @cols + ')
    ) p
 order by idx '

select @query -- use select to inspect the generated sql
--execute(@query) -- once satisfied that sql is OK, use execute
```

but you can't use @t as the data source when executing the @query.

I have no idea if this really helps because as there no columnar references back to Classes

---

**EDIT**

To replace NULLs in the final output requires changing the first query seen above to this:

```
SELECT
    idx
  , COALESCE( CAST( [C1] AS varchar ), '' )  -- converted into STRINGS
  , COALESCE( CAST( [C2] AS varchar ), '' )
  , COALESCE( CAST( [C3] AS varchar ), '' )
  , COALESCE( CAST( [D1] AS varchar ), '' )
  , COALESCE( CAST( [D2] AS varchar ), '' )
  , COALESCE( CAST( [D3] AS varchar ), '' )
  , COALESCE( CAST( [E1] AS varchar ), '' )
FROM (
    SELECT
        idx
      , head
      , qty
    FROM @t
    ) sourcedata
PIVOT
    (
    MAX( [qty] )
    FOR [head] IN ([C1], [C2], [C3], [D1], [D2], [D3], [E1])
    ) p
ORDER BY
    idx
```

Comment: Thanks! It's almost close to the question. but the output has two `row3`s and two `row5`s which are not collected in single row.

Comment: well spotted, remove class from the query... i'll edit

Comment: *Could the NULLs be shown as blank string ?*  NO and YES. NO because the data in the original column `qty` is an integer, so all the pivoted columns are also integers and yo cannot place `''` (which is an `empty string`) strings into any numeric column.  If you really really want `empty strings` in those columns then you would need to convert `qty` to a string first. I will edit answer.